# Can't share data between controllers using factory after first time change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I know that angularjs does two way data binding. I have two controllers that I'd like to talk to each other. I used a factory for them to communicate with each other. In the `AppCtrl` controller I assign  `Data.mydata.buildingName` to equal a name. Here's what I'm doing:

Call `AppCtrl`, and change the value of `buildingName`.

Then when I call `PathController`, it knows that the value of `buildingName` has changed and displays that.

**BUT when I go back to `AppCtrl`, and change the value of `buildingName` again, `PathController` doesn't seem to be knowing this.**

Can anyone please show me what I've done wrong here?

// factory

```
.factory('Data', function(){
    return { 
       mydata: {
           buildingName: 'Campus',
           shortName: 'Main',
           lattitude: '35.720031000963',
           longittude: '-87.343068987131'
       }
    };
})
```

// controller one

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, Data, $http, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

    // map location
    $scope.mapLocation = function(name, shortName, lattitude, longittude) {
        Data.mydata.buildingName= name;
        Data.mydata.shortName= shortName;
        Data.mydata.lattitude= lattitude;
        Data.mydata.longittude = longittude
        $scope.Data = Data.mydata;

        console.log("From AppCtrl: " +  Data.mydata.buildingName+ "  "+ Data.mydata.shortName+"  "+ Data.mydata.lattitude + " "+ Data.mydata.longittude );
        $scope.modal.hide();
    }
})
```

// controller two

```
.controller("PathController", [ '$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {

    $scope.Data = Data.mydata.buildingName;

    var name = Data.mydata.buildingName + " - " + Data.mydata.shortName;
    lattitude = Data.mydata.lattitude;
    longitude = Data.mydata.longittude;

    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: 35.720031000963,
            lng: -87.343068987131,
            zoom: 17
        },

        markers: {
           Campus: {
               lat: longitude,
               lng: lattitude,
               focus: true,
               draggable: false,
               message: name
           }, 
        },
    });
}])
```

Comment: Where is `mapLocation ()` called from? If it's in an event outside of angular will need to notify angular of changes to scope

Comment: @charlietfl  Map location is called through onClick in HTML.  (   <a ng-click="mapLocation(building.name, building.short_name, building.longitude, building.latitude)">   )  How would I notify angular of changes to the scope to the factory?

Answer (score 0):

In your `PathController`, `$scope.Data`, `lattitude`, `longittude`, and `name` are simply string values. Changing the properties of `Data.mydata` will not affect them.

One way to watch a value for changes and update your controller values accordingly is to use `$scope.$watch()`:

```
// add at the end of PathController
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return Data.mydata;
}, function (newValue) {
    $scope.Data = newValue.buildingName;
    $scope.markers.Campus.lat = newValue.lattitude;
    $scope.markers.Campus.long = newValue.longittude;
    $scope.markers.Campus.message = newValue.buildingName + " - " + newValue.shortName;
}, true /* check for object equality */);
```